Different behavior reason when overloading + and == operators
I have a class below;
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(int value) : data(value)
    {
    }
    
    MyClass operator+(int x) const
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass " << x << "\n";
        return MyClass{99};
    }
    
    bool operator==(int x) const
    {
        std::cout << "MyClass " << x << "\n";
        return true;
    }
    
    int data;
};

Both calls below are valid and have no errors
bool r = MyClass{5} ==  7;
bool r2 = 9 == MyClass{5};

But when I use the + operator I get an error for the 2nd call
MyClass r = MyClass{5} +  7;
MyClass r2 = 9 + MyClass{5};

error: invalid operands to binary expression

Since both operators are symmetric, I expect them to show the same behavior. Why does the error occur?
Sincerely.

The way you have defined the operators they are not symmetric, that is the problem. In particular defining an operator inside a class requires that the first parameter be an object of that class, there are no implicit conversions on the first parameter (but there are on the second). The solution to this is to define the operator outside of any class, so MyClass operator+(MyClass x, MyClass y) { ... }

@john your explanation isnt sound. OP sasy bool r2 = 9 == MyClass{5}; complies without error, but there is no implicit conversion involved (MyClass has no conversion to bool)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I think it's sound as far as it goes. The explanation for the different behaviour of operator== is presumably what is given in the answer below (which is new information to me).

Comparison operators got an upgrade in C++20 (along with introduction of <=>), which among other things makes == symmetric, lets you skip defining != (a != b behaves as !(a == b) when there's no custom !=), and so on.
This wasn't done for +. At least one reason is that (unlike ==) it's often not symmetric (e.g. for std::string).
